# inform symfony of where repository classes are located

Tags: symfony

I see in the [creating your own entity provider section](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html) that you put the `UserRepository` class in the `Entity` directory. Can you stray from this code organization? For example if i wanted a structure like this:

- MyCompany

  - MyProject

    - MyBundle

      - Controller
      - DependencyInjection
      - Entity
      - Repositories

        - doctrine

          - UserRespository.php
      - Resources
      - doc
      - public
      - translations
      - views

Can you inform symfony about where to locate the `UserRepository`?

Comment: Any reason to do so? I just wanna know

Comment: I'd just like to keep everything doctrine related into a place easily identifiable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyCompany\MyBundle\Repositories\doctrine\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In reading your doc :

```
/**
 * Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="acme_users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
```

So just replace the path by the path you want :

```
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyCompany\MyBundle\Repositories\doctrine\UserRepository")
```